# How to install Postler (From elementary)

Tags: 11.04, installation

When I try to install Postler from the Elementary OS web page (first by adding the repository and running apt-get update, then clicking "Install," the Software Center opens, then displays a "Not Found" error. The package is also not found when searching for it in the Software Center or by installing it from the command line.

Is there something I am missing? Dexter installed just fine, and I've tried Postler on the elementary live image, and I like it better than Thunderbird, so I'd like to use it.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity, though Unity shouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check me here, but I believe Elementary OS provides updates/software for 10.04 and 10.10.  That is, unless something has changed as of late, 11.04 is likely not supported.

Comment: Kory Wnuk is correct - here is a [link](http://elementaryos.org/psa/) to the elementary website about the incompatibility between elementary os and 11.04